# Installing extension

Tags: numpy

In shell I can't install numpy and it shows this error

[image]

Comment: Exit from IDLE and type those commands actually into your shell.

Comment: And how would I get there? :)

Comment: Open a Terminal (Linux) or Command prompt (Windows).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are typing 'shell' (operating system) commands into the Python interpreter, which only understands Python.

First, exit the Python interpreter with `exit()`.

Then type the shell command, `pip install numpy`.

Then you can re-enter the Python interpreter, e.g. by typing `python` and you should have access to NumPy with `import numpy as np` (for example).